# Appium: how to have android and ios selector in one property (C#)

Tags: appium

I'm testing mobile hybrid app. I have a problem. I would have android and ios selector in one property (web element). Any idea how to do that?

I tryed this :

```
    [FindsByAndroidUIAutomator(ID = "btStartLogin")]
    [FindsByIOSUIAutomation(XPath = "")]
    public AppiumWebElement LoginButton;
```

But not working - null object reference

This is working fine but only for one platform:

```
    public AppiumWebElement LoginButton => driver.FindElementById("btStartLogin");
```